# How do I reαd from an excel sheet within Sharepoint?

Tags: python, sharepoint, jupyter-notebook, office365

Currently I'm working on a project that involves taking an excel sheet stored in Sharepoint, reading it as a dataframe in Pandas, and then doing some other things to it that aren't relevant to this question. My issue stems from the fact that my company uses 2 factor authentication to log into our accounts, and I cant quite figure out how to bypass that.

Also, because it might be relevant: I'm working in jupyter notebook.

My code currently looks like this:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 

url = 'https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/COMPANYNAME/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
username = "USER"
password = "PASSWORD"

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)

if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start


df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheetname = None)
```

I get the response:

`ValueError: Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf` from line 18 (`ctx.execute_query()`).

I'm a bit lost on what to try, I've read a couple of articles but none of them have been any major help, so any advice from here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Doesnt this help https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master#2-using-username-and-password?

Its based on the package that you are importing

Comment: It also has an example like this -> https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/connect_with_user_credential.py